# How to change background color of xml by using spinner

Tags: android, xml, spinner

I want to change the color of XML based on the value selected in the spinner. Here is the code that i had tried.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener{
Spinner obj;
String[] str={"Red","Green","Yellow","Gray"};
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
ViewGroup vg;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    obj=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    vg=(ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.relative);
adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getBaseContext(),android.R.
layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,str);
obj.setAdapter(adapter);
    obj.setOnItemClickListener(this);
}
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
String color=obj.getSelectedItem().toString();
    if(color=="Red")
    {

    }
}



}
```

Iam trying to use setBackground method but it gives me error

Comment: where is your `setBackground` method? what error are you getting?

Comment: "change the color of XML..." !! the question sounds different...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the xml has a relative layout, or any main layout. On Item selected call, get the layout, and use setbackground(getResources().getColor(R.color.color_name_here).

Hope that helps.!

Comment: Thanks. It worked though i didnt had to call getResource(). Just in the setBackground i called Color.color_name and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Try below code!

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
  String color=str[arg2];  //where arg2 is position of selected item
  if(color=="Red")
  {
      View someView = findViewById(R.id.randomViewInMainLayout);

      // Find the root view
      View root = someView.getRootView()

     // Set the color
      root.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
  }
```

}

Comment: It worked but once a color set then it doesn't change to other color when i select other value.

Comment: if(color=="Blue")
  {
      View someView = findViewById(R.id.randomViewInMainLayout);

      // Find the root view
      View root = someView.getRootView()

     // Set the color
      root.setBackgroundColor(android.R.color.blue);
  } did you write other cases other than Red ?

Comment: Try this one instead of android.R.color.red, root.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED); it is working perfectly in my case

Comment: If still you are not getting it perfectly then I will share my code.

Answer (score 0):

get the id og your main layout like

```
    Yourlayout(linear or realtive) layout = (Yourlayout)findviewbyid(R.id.yourlayoutid);
```

on on click of spinner

```
 if(color=="Red")
   {
    layout.setbackground(getResources().getColor(R.color.color_name_here);
   }
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked. I didn't had to call getResource(). Just used Color.color_name in setBackground() and it worked.